# What is the proper way to write a professional email to a business?

Tags: politeness, email, business-japanese

I'm not sure how I would write a professional email to a business in Japanese. For example, if I wanted to start out with "Hello," I wouldn't say こんにちは, would I? I know there are polite ways of saying things in Japanese, including special conjugations for verbs.

Basically I would like to know how to start out an email, ways to write the body professionally, and end politely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's say you're writing to a certain Mr. Tanaka Tarou, who's the representative director of the XYZ corporation. I would write the email on the following lines, where I put more than one example just to give you some ideas.

**件名 - object:**

- 【△△社】○○参考資料{さんこうしりょう}のご送付{そうふ}
- ○月○日のお打ち合わせのお礼

**宛名 - Addressee:**

株式会社{かぶしきがいしゃ}XYZ

代表取締役{だいひょうとりしまりやく} 田中太郎様

**あいさつ文 - greetings:**

- お世話になっております。株式会社YOUR_COMPANYのGabby Quattroneでございます。
- お世話になっております。株式会社YOUR_COMPANYのGabby Quattroneと申します。
- ご無沙汰{ぶさた}しております (if you haven't written for some time)

**内容 - contents:**

This pretty much depends on what you want to say so I will skip it. The important thing is to maintain throughout this part a formal and polite linguistic register.

**結びの文 - Conclusions:**

- 今後ともどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。
- 引き続きどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。
- お手数おかけしますが、何卒{なにとぞ}よろしくお願いいたします。

Below is a full mock email:

```
○○会社営業部 部長 
××様 
いつも大変お世話になっております。 
株式会社△△の田中です。 

このたびは、お忙しいなか、貴重な時間を割いていただき誠にありがとうございました。 
貴社とのお取引開始を、大変喜ばしく思っております。 
今後、改めて御社のご要望に十分添った形で、 
製品精度を高めていく所存です。 

また、ご不明な点等ございましたらご連絡ください。 
今後とも、どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。
```

I put a bit of my own here and there and took some examples and the last email from [here](https://gakumado.mynavi.jp/freshers/articles/40095).

Comment: Can you use furigana? There are some parts I can't read immediately such as 資料. Thank you!

Comment: On all of it??? o_O

Comment: No, I understand most of it. Sorry! I could write here which ones I do not.

Comment: If it is too much trouble, I can search it up myself later. Thank you again! ^^;

Comment: @GabbyQuattrone No worries I put some in there, I skipped the last mock email if you don't mind.